# WCF Service always returning discovery page when run locally

Tags: ssl, wcf, wcf-discovery

Using the WCF Test Client I get this when trying to invoke a method:

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
> not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
> If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
> method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response
> were: '#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em;
> MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000;
> FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY:
> Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px;
> BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
> FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid;
> PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY:
> Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px;
> PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px;
> MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH:
> 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
> BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT:
> -15px}TagService Service</HEAD'.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IDataTagService.GetTagDefinitions(String projectID, Nullable`1 tagType)
   at DataTagServiceClient.GetTagDefinitions(String projectID, Nullable`1 tagType)
```

Which appears to me to be the discovery page. This works when deployed, but not locally? This also used to work locally, but somehow has started displaying this behavior. I'm not sure what could have changed to make this suddenly break.

Edit: I've narrowed it down to this:

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

if I change it to none and use an http url, it works, but I'd like my local copy to mirror production so does anyone have any idea how I can get to the root cause of this?

Edit: I've uninstalled and reinstalled IIS, ran the applications to get asp.net and wcf working with IIS, enabled ssl, and am right back to where I started. ARGH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by securitySwitch not being turned off, or at least not having a configuration. Putting

```
<secureWebPages mode="Off" ignoreHandlers="None">
</secureWebPages>
```

resolved the problem, and is overwritten by a web.release.config transform.

it was previously just `<secureWebPages />`

http://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/